streaming live video live label detection example
Is there a code example detailed in step by step explaining how to achieve live label detection in
Google cloud video intelligence api?
Thanks
I was going through the documentation regarding the same but couldn't clearly understand what were the steps.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
